# What geological/geographical features are needed to support a Greco-Roman 'City of Fountains'

Tags: physics, geography, cities

Belsaria is the City of Fountains. The capital of Nowheria, it's truly a civic marvel, due to the thousands of fountains that jet water into the air at every intersection and in the courtyards of almost all the houses.

Built at a similar time to Rome, the architects of Belsaria were masters of aqueducts, reservoirs and canals, innately understanding the flow of water, and the masonry techniques and materials needed to direct and control it.

What I need to know is where Belsaria needs to be located, how much water pressure might be needed to support a series of impressive gravity fed fountains, and what kind of geographical features might be required to allow for a city covered in such beautiful and wondrous items.

Edit for clarity: I'm trying to maximise the number of fountains that it's possible to have per square mile in the city. Geographical features (even extreme ones) that help with this are welcome suggestions)

Comment: There is a popular saying: "Rome wasn't built in a day". Nobody just constructed that city and started to built it. Maybe you are confusing it with Constantinople. But people in the time Rome was "built" didn't really plan ahead that much. They also didn't like wasting ressources on fountains, but that isn't the point. Btw, you already stated that this would best be done with gravity, so there needs to be a hill with e.g. a lake and some pipes. What else do you want to know? Exact blueprints? Your question could use some work. Also you are vague. "A series" isn't a well defined number

Comment: Nowheria? The Land of Nowhere, perhaps. The Latin word for nowhere is "nusquam". While it isn't euphonious Nusquamia might be more apt.

Comment: @Raditz_35 : 1:Rome wasn't built in a day: but it was built in a location. What location would be favourable to lots of fountains? 2: nobody wastes resources until they feel they can, but being in a place that lets you build fountains means that when you can you naturally think to build fountains. 3: yes, I'm vague, because the geographical features required greatly affect the potential size (and therefore number of fountains) of the city. Ideally equations on water pressure and volumes, along with ideas that can be exploited for maximum of both, is the aim of the question

Comment: @a4android: cue me renaming an entire empire.

Comment: The geographical features required are mountains where there are sources of water which are connected to Belsaria by aqueducts. You will have researched https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fountain#Ancient_Roman_fountains

Comment: Rome is full of fountains which attract many many tourists. You cannot walk five minutes pre-modern part of the city without seeing at least one. Those fountains were built during the Renaissance and Early Modern periods, not in the Antiquity, but waterworks technology was not so much different. [List of fountains in Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fountains_in_Rome) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Chatsworth House](https://www.chatsworth.org/)

That's as obscure a reference as any, but one of the things Chatsworth is famous for is the fountain.

[The Emperor Fountain](https://www.chatsworth.org/garden/history-of-the-garden/6th-duke-paxton/emperor-fountain/) was the highest in the world, reaching 90m, when it was built in 1843. It's gravity powered by a lake in the hills 122m above the house.

This is really a game about plumbing. The [shorter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation) and [straighter](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/21/jresv21n1p1_A1b.pdf) your pipes the less pressure loss as the water moves from source to fountain. The lower the pressure loss the higher your fountains will be relative to their source.

- If you run the pipes with kinks and bends and junctions all round the houses of the town your fountains won't be particularly impressive.
- If you run a straight pipe from the source to each fountain you'll get the maximum effect for the highest cost.

Geographically it's a minor detail, all you need is a lake you can use as a reservoir that sits higher than your town. Such features are not uncommon in temperate zones. The key is not to be taking so much water from your lake that it runs dry halfway through tourist season taking your drinking water supply with it. The Chatsworth fountain runs at no more than half power and only on special occasions because of the high water flow through its 40cm pipe.

Comment: Useful stuff!!!

Comment: Nice example plus good plumbing advice. Plus one for practicalities.

Answer (score 0):

You could also build up water pressure through putting your city at the foot of a mountain range. Then all the collected water would be pulled down to the city where it could be put through the plumbing system to the fountains. This would allow for the water to be fresh and pleasant to drink, although it would be cold. This would not be too bad in a hot location, which would be another important factor as this mountain range could not be anywhere that snows. Snow would make the water flow irregular. In winter you wouldn't get any as it would be frozen on top of the mountain, and in Spring and Summer it would cause flash floods.